# Is "sign up to" an acceptable alternative to "sign up for" on websites?

Tags: programming

I generally see "sign up for" online, but I've noticed "sign up to" in a few places. Is that an acceptable alternative when talking about signing up for a service?

For example, [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/account-selection) says "It's free to sign up to PayPal." Is "PayPal" serving as a verb in that case?

The same for the title of the Airbnb sign up page: "log in/sign up to Airbnb".

Comment: "*I've noticed "sign up to" in a few places.*" You could you point to an example or two, where we can see the expression in context?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Just added two examples.

Comment: I don't see the phrase "sign up to PayPal." in the page you have linked to. Nor can I find  an Airbnb page with the claimed title.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I guess you can just Google "paypal 'sign up to'" and "airbnb 'sign up to'", then. The title for the Airbnb page shows up only in the titlebar, not in the content of the page.

Comment: The Paypal example supports your good observation/question, but I think the "Airbnb" example is more an issue of them just trying to avoid having to use the rather clumsy "to/for" to cover perfectly the preceding "Log in [to]/Sign up [for],"="log in/sign up to/for Airbnb."  Granted since "Sign up" is the second option, perhaps "for" would have read more smoothly, but working backwards, it would have made the "Log in [for]" option sound weird, too, imo.

Comment: @TinMan I guess you greatly overestimate the amount of time I am willing to devote to **your** question.

Comment: Please provide specific links.

Comment: @aparente001 This is the Airbnb page: https://www.airbnb.com/signup_login

Comment: I can't find the phrase "sign up to."  I would suggest you put a screenshot in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms are not the same, but similar.

You sign up for (*a noun*, like hockey or excitement), and sign up to (*a verb*, like win, or play hockey).

Sign up **for** fun.
Sign up **to** have fun.

Sign up **for** the time of your life.
Sign up **to** have the time of your life.

How *sign up to* (PayPal or Airbnb) makes sense, I do not know. Paypal does not serve as a verb, but then anything goes on the internet, not necessarily serving as an example of good style.

Comment: I've added some details to my question. (I don't think it will change your answer, but it's more concrete.)